# How to make one MySQL User to access only one schema

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have searched a lot about "How to allow access of One User only on One Schema", but not found any convincing solution. I have read about `GRANT` and `REVOKE` but found the solutions like grant or revoke the permissions on a particular tables for particular user.

What I am looking for is, When having multiple Users, each have access to defined Schema's and one user will have full access rights to One Schema.
And I don't want one user to access the other Schema's except the one for which access rights are given.

Please suggest how to exactly use the `GRANT` or `REVOKE` to perform this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **To give all accesses of your `YOUR_PARTICULAR_SCHEMA` to a particular
  user named `USERNAME` from a particular `IP ADDRESS (in this case xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)`:**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON YOUR_PARTICULAR_SCHEMA.* TO 'USERNAME'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

- **To give all accesses of your `YOUR_PARTICULAR_SCHEMA` to a particular
  user named `USERNAME` from any`IP ADDRESS (use wildcard operator %)` :**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON YOUR_PARTICULAR_SCHEMA.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

- **To give all accesses of all your `Schemas` to a particular
  user named `USERNAME` from a particular`IP ADDRESS (in this case 1.2.3.4)` :**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

- **To give all accesses of all your `Schemas` to a particular
  user named `USERNAME` from a any`IP ADDRESS (use wildcard operator %)` :**

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

**Note:** Your scenario lies in the first two cases. You may pick any one of them based on your choice.

**EDIT:** If you want to remove privileges from a user who has been granted privileges previously then use [**REVOKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html) command.

> REVOKE removes privileges, but does not drop mysql.user table entries.
> To remove a user account entirely, use DROP USER

Comment: Thanks. Second Option worked for me.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON YOUR_PARTICULAR_SCHEMA.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

This helped me to create two different users having rights to two databases, and not affecting each others database structure.
When tried to login with user one to database two, it given the `Access Denied` error. Which was exactly needed.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. You are welcome :) @MandarPandit

Answer (score 0):

**Here how to grant one MySQL User to access only one schema**

On the Administration tab in `Workbench`
goto Users and Privileges
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYUJO.png)
select the user that you need
goto the Administrative Roles tab and clear all roles and privileges
goto the Schema Privileges press on Add Entry... button
then select the schema radio button and your desired schema and Ok button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMWYS.png)
Back to the Schema Privileges tab, select the schema entry you just added, and select the Rights you wish to give to the user.

finally press on apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).